# when creating a model , mongodb error in department

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

when i made a request here http://localhost:3000/company i am getting an error like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUcVn.png)imgur.com/Ng3GH.png) , [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eCy7.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNEQF.png)

this is controllers , postman , schema

Comment: Everything you showed in images should be added as text to the question, including that comment

Comment: You should also show the body you send using postman

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.